# How can I split string with dot in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have make target like this:

```
test.%
    export var1=$(basename $*) && export var2=$(subst .,,$(suffix $*))
```

and I use like  `test.var1.var2`

Now I want to do one more level like  `test.var1.var2.var3`. How can I get that in a Makefile?

edit:

The reason I want to do this is because I am using Makefile for deploying multiple apps. And I want many variables. So that user can deploy like

```
make install.{app1}.{test}.{build_number}
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why exactly do you need to do this?

Comment: @user657267 i have edited the question

Comment: Looks like an overly complicated way of doing `make app=app1 action=test build=4.2.1`.

Comment: @user657267 OP's usage is trivial, but IMHO in more complex cases working with dynamic targets (e.g. `test-{app1,app2,...}`) makes life much easier.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `subst` to replace dots with spaces so that it becomes a list. Then use `word` to access a specific element:

```
word-dot = $(word $2,$(subst ., ,$1))

test.%:
    export var1=$(call word-dot,$*,1) && export var2=$(call word-dot,$*,2) && export var3=$(call word-dot,$*,3)
```

Which outputs:

```
$ make test.foo.bar.baz
export var1=foo && export var2=bar && export var3=baz
```

*As an aside* (that will actually take up most of my answer), if you know in advance what the options are, you could go with some robust metaprogramming. Say you want to generate `test-{app}` targets for some `APPS`:

```
tmpl-for = $(foreach x,$2,$(call $1,$x))
rule-for = $(foreach x,$2,$(eval $(call $1,$x)))

APPS := foo bar baz

tmpl-test = test-$1

define test-vars-rule
$(call tmpl-test,$1): APP := $1
.PHONY: $(call tmpl-test,$1)
endef

$(call rule-for,test-vars-rule,$(APPS))
$(call tmpl-for,tmpl-test,$(APPS)):
        @echo Testing app: $(APP)
```

The first two lines are "library" functions that will call a "template" (`tmpl-for`) or generate a rule (`rule-for`) for each element in the list you provide as the second argument. I create a `tmpl-test` which takes the app name and gives `test-{app}`. I define a rule template which takes the app name and sets a target-specific `APP` variable for the appropriate `test-{app}` target (which is also made phony by the way). Then I use `rule-for` to create all my rules for setting `APP`. Finally I write the actual body of my target, and I get the list of all possible targets using `tmpl-for`.

```
$ make test-foo
Testing app: foo
$ make test-bar
Testing app: bar
$ make test-baz
Testing app: baz
$ make test-blah
make: *** No rule to make target 'test-blah'.  Stop.
```

It sounds complex, and it is, but if you properly abstract the templating functions it can produce flexible and easily maintainable build systems.

Comment: Thanks dude this what i was lokking for