# Gnu make with multiple % in pattern rule?

Tags: makefile

If I understand the make documentation correctly I can only use character % once in my target-pattern!

I am facing a condition which my target is look like:

`$(Home)/ecc_%_1st_%.gff: %.fpp`

And whenever I am trying to match `/home/ecc_map_1st_map.gff: map.fpp`
Make complains that can't find a pattern.

I know it is because of using % twice (`$(Home)/ecc_map_1st_%.gff: %.fpp` runes perfectly)

Is there anyway which I can use two % in one target!?

Thanks

Comment: what is the need to have word `map` twice in the file name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match double stem in target like %/% or other way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404646/how-to-match-double-stem-in-target-like-or-other-way)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two patterns. The best way would be not having `map` twice in the target name.

If you must, and you're using GNU make, [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) might be useful:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(Home)/ecc_%.gff: $$(word 1,$$(subst _, ,$$*)).fpp
```

Normally you can't use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) such as `$*` in prerequisites, but secondary expansion allows you to do just that. Note that I used `$$` in place of `$` so that the real expansion happens in the second pass and not in the first one.

Say you are making `$(Home)/ecc_map_1st_map.gff`. The `$*` variable is going to be the stem, i.e. `map_1st_map`. Then `$(subst _, ,...)` replaces underscores with spaces, to obtain `map 1st map`. Now `$(word N,...)` extracts the N-th space-separated word in there. First word would be the first `map`, second would be `1st`, third would be the second `map`. I'm picking the first one.

Of course this is pretty lax and doesn't guarantee you'll match exactly the targets you wanted (`$(Home)/ecc_map_2nd_notmap__foo.gff` would match and give `map.fpp`). You could do further checks (`1st` in the middle, other two must match) and bail out:

```
extract-name = $(call extract-name-helper,$1,$(word 1,$(subst _, ,$1)))
extract-name-helper = $(if $(filter $2_1st_$2,$1),$2,$(error Invalid .gff target))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
ecc_%.gff: $$(call extract-name,$$*).fpp
```

But that doesn't look like a sensible solution.

Wrapping up, if don't have similarly named files, then the first solution would work well. Also, if you know the target names beforehand, you could make it safer with an explicit pattern rule (or even generate them [on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124162/6644919)).